# Changing a variable value from a function in a function

Tags: javascript

```js
function addMe() {
  var a = 2;
  var vid = document.createElement('video');
  vid.src = URL.createObjectURL(myFile.files[0]);
  vid.ondurationchange = function() {
    a = 7;
  };
  console.log(a);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="myFile">
<button onclick="addMe()">Click</button>
```

I expect the value of `a` to be 7 since I have changed it with the `vid.ondurationchange` function. When I checked the value of `a` inside the `vid.ondurationchange`, it was 7 but when I checked the value outside it, it was 2. Since the `vid.ondurationchange` is local to the `addMe`function, I want to change the value of `a` from the `vid.ondurationchange` function.

Comment: The value of `a` will change once `ondurationchange` event fires. The reason your `console.log(a)` outputs `2` is because it is logged before `ondurationchange` fires and reassigns the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `console.log` runs immediately, without waiting for `ondurationchange` to happen. That's why it logs the initial value. If you need to check that the value actually changed, then you would want to use that console.log inside `ondurationchange` (like you mentioned doing), since that's when the new value is actually available.